# android key store entries cleaning

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have an app that uses AndroidKeystore, and I wanted to cleanup my app specific key entries from Android Key Store, when my app got uninstalled(so, app does not have much control to call deleteEntry).

I believe that android cleans up when my app got uninstalled, but I donno how to confirm. I could not find much info on clenaup on android-dev either.

Can anybody confirm or give help on how we be sure that an app's keystore entries will be deleted when that app is uninstalled ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your keystore keys are automatically removed when your app is deleted.  Specifically, whenever an app is deleted, [PackageManagerService.removeKeyStoreDataIfNeeded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r30/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#18570) is called.  This calls [KeyStoreService::clear_uid](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/security/+/android-9.0.0_r30/keystore/key_store_service.cpp#689) which finds and removes all key aliases for the specified app UID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the keys will be removed from [AndroidKeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UsingAndroidKeyStore) . In order tu assure it, you can use methods that create the key if it doesn't exist after `KeyStore.getInstance()` call and verify those are being called upon app-uninstall.

```
private static void init() throws KeyStoreException {

    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    try {
        keyStore = loadKeystore();
    } catch (CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
        Log.w(Constants.TAG, "GENERATING KEYS");
        //KEY ABSENT, generate it

    }else{
        //EXISTING KEY
    }
}
```

Also see [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322042/does-keystore-entry-will-be-lost-when-application-is-uninstalled)