# Flutter - Get external storage path for IOS to store authentication files securely

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am looking for a solution to get the external path for the IOS platform to store some authentication files which should not be deleted even though my application is being uninstalled. Is there any way to achieve this with the solution I am looking for or any other technique could be used.
All suggestions are welcomed,
Thanks for help.

Comment: what kind of authentication you use?\

Comment: I am generating an application Key and storing it in a .device file

Comment: did you try the path_provider package

Comment: yeah, but it only provides Application Directory path which is deleted while uninstalling the application

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem outside of the application sandbox.  You could store data in the keychain; that will persist across application delete/re-inistall

Comment: @Paulw11 can you provide some sort of example, I don't know how to store data in keychain

Comment: @YogeshChawla see my answer below. Use [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to store files securely.

Comment: @om-ha Will values stored in Keychain and KeyStore survive app uninstallation ?

Comment: @YogeshChawla They should for KeyChain but this is not encouraged and not future-proof. They definitely don't for Keystore. Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Storing Authentication Files Securely

For storing files, if you were to store authentication files then you'd have to do so in a secure manner. i.e. [KeyChain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) on iOS and [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) on Android. [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) pub encapsulates this for you.

#### Persisting information and surviving app uninstallation

As per your second point, your stored authentication files cannot survive uninstallation. You have to use [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) for iOS and [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet) for Android. Which offers storing bare minimum information (two bits on iOS!) and associating them with the device.

KeyChain may support this for now, but this is not guaranteed to be future-proof. KeyStore certainly [does not support this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325725/10830091).

You can also check out the following articles for more insights:

- [What Role do DeviceCheck and SafetyNet play in App Authentication?](https://hackernoon.com/what-role-do-devicecheck-and-safetynet-play-in-app-authentication-a0c525599d19)
- [The Travelled iOS Developer -- Device Check](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/devicecheck-6f3eafac60e5)
- [DeviceCheck API Unique Identifier for the iOS Devices](https://developerinsider.co/devicecheck-api-unique-identifier-for-the-ios-devices/)
- [Device Check Tutorial](https://fluffy.es/devicecheck-tutorial/)